# What command does Ctrl+C execute?

Tags: command-line, firefox, shortcuts, search, copy

I want to create a shortcut in Ubuntu which would open new tab and search for selected text in Firefox. For example, if I get some error I would select it press the shortcut and the new search would be opened.

I would add shortcut through Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts.
I know that I can open new tab through:

```
firefox --new-tab --url about:newtab
```

What I do not know is how to copy selected text or in other words what command does Ctrl+C execute? And how do I combine them?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean I could, but why? I am already using select + Ctrl+C + Ctrl+T + Ctrl+V + Enter, and I am finding that I use that combination a lot of times, so why not automate. I tried to enter a combination of shortcuts but it does not accept. I could also make a python script that would be run on the shortcut press but that would be just a hassle.

Comment: `Ctrl-C` is used to interrupt the current process, it doesn't "run a command". Read `man kill signal stty`

Comment: Okey, I  can edit the post to correct it. I am not searching for some specific way but rather for a way to make this combination of actions (search selected in new tab and switch to it) possible. Thanks!

Comment: Some clipboard managers (`klipper` for instance) can run "actions" on clipped items.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't actually run any command. It sends [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT), i.e., Interrupt signal to the process running in foreground.

From [Signal (IPC) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT):

> #### SIGINT
>
> The SIGINT signal is sent to a process by its controlling terminal when a user wishes to **interrupt** the process. This is typically initiated by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but on some systems, the "delete" character or "break" key can be used.

If you want to copy text from terminal, you should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Can I somehow combine Ctrl+Shift+C with commands to launch new firefox tab with the selected text searched, and then pres just one shortcut?